# Missing # inserted in tabular mode

Tags: tables, preamble, missing

I'm somewhat new to Latex. Right now, I'm stuck with table creation. After searching this and other forums, I didn't manage to sort this out yet, so I kindly ask for your support. If I missed the answer to thins on some other thread, please apologize me in advance.

Below you'll find my document's preamble and the table in question. I tried many approaches both on the table coding and the preamble, but none seemed to work. This code returns the following error:

> Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
> to be read again
> & l.127 ...in{tabularx}{| C{4cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} |}
> There should be exactly one # between &'s, and an \halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had none, so I've put one in; maybe this will work.

Looking forward to your support, with kind regards,

```
\documentclass[portuguese,a4paper, 10pt,twoside,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel,varioref}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[cdot,squaren]{SIunits}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{emptypage} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
%\usepackage{tweaklist}
\usepackage[english,portuges]{babel,varioref}
%\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[normalmargins,normalleading]{savetrees}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,lipsum}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}
%\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\makeindex[columns=3, title=Índice Alfabético]

\usepackage{indentfirst} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{3.cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3.cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{cont}{#1 \textit{\textbf{(continuação)}}#2#3\par}

% Comentários footnote sem númeração

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\input{RDM2021_Trab1_Cover}

%\newpage

%Índice
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{C C C}
\begin{tabular}{| C{4cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} |}
\hline \textbf{Gás de Efeito de Estufa} & \textbf{Fórmula} & \textbf{GWP a 100 anos}\\
\hline \textit{Dióxido de carbono} & $CO_2$ & 1 \\
\hline \textit{Metano} & $CH_4$ & 25 \\
\hline \textit{Óxido Nitroso} & $N_2O$ & 298 \\
\hline \textit{Hexafluoreto de Enxofre} & $SF_6$ & 22.800 \\
\hline \textit{Trifluormetano} & $CHF_3$ & 14.800 \\
\hline \textit{Difluormetano} & $CH_2F_2$ & 675 \\
\hline \textit{Tetrafluormetano} & $CF_4$ & 7.390 \\
\hline \textit{Hexafluoretano} & $C_2F_6$ & 12.200 \\
\hline \textit{Octafluorpropano} & $C_3F_8$ & 8.830 \\
\hline \textit{Perfluorbutano} & $C_4F_{10}$ & 8.860 \\
\hline \textit{Octafluorciclobutano} & $C_4F_8$ & 10.300 \\
\hline \textit{Perfluorpentano} & $C_5F_{12}$ & 13.300 \\
\hline \textit{Perfluorhexano} & $C_6F_{14}$ & 9.300 \\
\hline \textit{Black Carbon} & - & 900 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}   
\caption{Valores de $CO_{2-eq}$ para alguns GHG. \cite{ref:CO2eq}}
\label{Tab:CO2-eq}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that a `tabularx` environment takes **two** arguments. The first is the width of the table; the second is the column specification. You've only supplied the latter. Use `\begin{tabularx}{<length>}{<col spec>}`. However, if you're using fixed-width columns, there's no need for `tabularx`, unless there's also some `X`-column in there (which there isn't). So, rather use `\begin{tabular}{<col spec>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very same error message you get with your document can also be reproduced with the
following a lot more minimal document and seems to be related to the combination of `array` and `ftnxtra`. If you wish to keep the latter package, invert the load order of the two packages and load `ftnxtra` before `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline 
\end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

While this fixes the error message and at least makes your code compilable, there are more issues with your preamble that you should address: Please make sure you only load packages you really need and if so, only load them once. Also make sure, `hyperref` is teh last package in your preamble (there are only a few exceptions that should be loaded after `hyperref`). Also, I suggest switching from `SIunits` with `siunitx` by which the former was superseeded.

Regarding the table's contents intelf: Since your second column contains chemical formulae, I would also like to encourage you to use a package dedicated from them (such as `chemformula` or `mhchem`) instead of using math mode to get the subscript numbers.

In the following MWE, I also used the before mentioned `siunitx` package to align the numbers in the last column and used lines from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{group-separator=., group-minimum-digits=4}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Valores de \ch{CO_{2-eq}} para alguns GHG. \cite{ref:CO2eq}}
\label{Tab:CO2-eq}
\begin{tabular}{llS[table-format=5]}
\toprule
{Gás de Efeito de Estufa} & {Fórmula} & {GWP a 100 anos}\\
\midrule
Dióxido de carbono      & \ch{CO2}   & 1 \\
Metano                  & \ch{CH4}   & 25 \\
Óxido Nitroso           & \ch{N2O}   & 298 \\
Hexafluoreto de Enxofre & \ch{SF6}   & 22800 \\
Trifluormetano          & \ch{CHF3}  & 14800 \\
Difluormetano           & \ch{CH2F2} & 675 \\
Tetrafluormetano        & \ch{CF4}   & 7390 \\
Hexafluoretano          & \ch{C2F6}  & 12200 \\
Octafluorpropano        & \ch{C3F8}  & 8830 \\
Perfluorbutano          & \ch{C4F10} & 8860 \\
Octafluorciclobutano    & \ch{C4F8}  & 10300 \\
Perfluorpentano         & \ch{C5F12} & 13300 \\
Perfluorhexano          & \ch{C6F14} & 9300 \\
Black Carbon            & ---        & 900 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```